# Returning the dynamic array overlap value in aggregate

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to return the dynamic array overlap value in aggregate? The database I am using is PostgreSQL 13. Let me paint the picture...

#### The Test Table

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
    id BIGSERIAL,
    group_id bigint NOT NULL,
    groups bigint[] NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

#### The Test Data

```sql
INSERT INTO test (group_id, groups) 
VALUES 
(1, '{123, 321}'), (1, '{321, 123}'),
(2, '{999, 111}'), (2, '{111, 999}');
```

#### The Current Aggregate Query

```sql
SELECT 
    group_id, MAX(groups)
FROM 
    test
WHERE
    groups && ARRAY[999, 123]::bigint[] GROUP BY group_id;
```

#### The Current Aggregate Query Result

```
| group_id | groups     |
|----------|------------|
| 1        | {321, 123} |
| 2        | {999, 111} |
```

#### My Desired Aggregate Query Result

```
| group_id | groups     | overlapped_at |
|----------|------------|---------------|
| 1        | {321, 123} | 123           |
| 2        | {999, 111} | 999           |
```

I want to to know which integer caused the overlap in a single query or transaction. Any ideas?

Comment: What if both integers match?  Should overlapped_at be an array instead?

Comment: Are the groups within a group_id always contain 2 rows per group_id and always in arrangement {A,B} and {B,A}?

Answer (score 1):

The solution I came up with was to use a custom function. This works for me as my groups are never more than two ints/bigints. If the groups were bigger I could see a more robust answer needed.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION intersects(anyarray, anyarray)
  RETURNS bigint
  language sql
as $FUNCTION$
    SELECT (ARRAY(
        SELECT UNNEST($1)
        INTERSECT
        SELECT UNNEST($2)
    )::bigint[])[1]::bigint;
$FUNCTION$;
```